# Printing content of an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

This generates the array.

```
public word (String file)
{...
    public int[] getArray()
    {       
       int[] array = {... } ;
       return array;
       }
}
```

And I need to reference that array in another class

```
public static void main()
{
    word numarray = new word("doc.txt");
    int [] heightarray =  numarray.getArray();
    System.out.println(heightarray);
}
```

I'm not getting any errors but I get things like [I@1a6fa30c as a result.

Comment: If you want to print it, use heightarray.toString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are getting in the output is the hashcode of the array. In order to print the contents of the array you can you either of the below options :

**Option 1 :** Print the elements one by one using a loop a below  :

```
for(int val : heightarray)
{
   System.out.print(val + ",");
}
```

**Option 2 :** Use Arrays utility class for printing the array

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(heightarray));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can print it using the Arrays.toString() method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(heightarray));
```